# MySQL Assembly C#. Update problem

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

my project has a dependency from the mysql assembly, and it looks like I strictly linked to the mysql assembly version. Few days ago I made an update of the assembly (5.x) and put the latest one (6.x) and as a result all related to my project projects thrown error that the mysql assembly (5.x) couldn't be found

How I can avoid it? I can't just recompiled depended projects.

Regards,
Cyril

Answer (score 0):

i guess what you did is add a reference to the dll itself.
which the project now is looking for.
you can remove the reference from the project,
create a bin directory, and put the files there.
then you can reference the mysql lib.